# using in_array return next array if the in_array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$array = array(
    array('a', '18:27:15', 'label1'),
    array('b', '18:27:20', 'label2'),
    array('c', '18:27:25', 'label3'),
    array('d', '18:27:30', 'label4'),
    array('e', '18:27:35', 'label5'),
    array('f', '18:27:40', 'label6'),
    array('g', '18:27:45', 'label7'),
    array('h', '18:27:50', 'label8')
);
```

Im checking to see whether have time string in the array,for example if i give

```
 $end_time="18:27:25";
```

I get the array result , but if I give

```
$end_time="18:27:26";
```

I get an empty array.
But I need it to return the next array instead that is

```
array('d','18:27:30','label4')
```

Below is the code

```
$arr_output = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$arr1){
    if( in_array($end_time, $arr1) ){
        $arr_output[$key]=$arr1;
    }
}
print_r(arr_output);//Empty
```

Comment: Anybody can help me ?

Comment: You can start by helping yourself. Your arrays appear to be sorted by time -- are they? If they are, those time strings look very conveniently comparable. Perhaps you could compare something to something else?

Comment: if i post $end_time="18:27:26"; how to return array('d', '18:27:30', 'label4')is the question....

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to timestamps and compare:

```
$result = null;
$target = strtotime('18:27:41');

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $compare = strtotime($item[1]);

    if ($compare >= $target) {
        if (null === $result) {
            $result = $item;
        } else if($target - strtotime($result[1]) < $target - $compare) {
            $result = $item;
        }
    }
}

echo print_r($result, 1);
```

With this approach, `:20` will point to `18:27:20`, and `:21` will point to `18:27:25`.

**Note** that this approach does not need the original array to be in any particular order, as each item is considered.